# Error "Invalid query parameter $dis " from feathersjs (nodejs framework)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, feathersjs, feathers-sequelize

I am facing an invalid query parameter error from feathersjs back end . i am using react as front end. My request is .

I did not write this code initially. the $includeEc was already there, but that does not create an error. I know $include, $limit are there too and $limit is a feathersjs query.

If I remove `$dis`, there is no error. I need `$dis` to validate something on my API.

```
let data = {
    $include: true,
    $includeEc: true,
    $limit: -1,
    $dis: 91,
  };

let res = await client.service('servicerequest').find({ query: data });
```

If I remove `$dis` there is no problem.

Comment: for some reason, when i add 3 backticks, the whole code is not shown as code in above post.

Comment: You need to put the three backticks on their **own line** - see my edits

Answer (score 0):

Custom query parameters prefixed with a `$` must be explicitly allowed on your feathers service. This was added in feathers 4 in order to improve the default security profile and prevent unwanted params from being passed into the db adapters.

From your example, `$limit` is part of the common query interface, while the two `$include` params are likely pre-configured or otherwise allowed by your DB adapter.

Read more about it here: **[Feathers Service Adapters: Whitelisting](https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/migrating.html#whitelisting)**